# iOS UITableViewCell dynamic sized tableview cell with imageview and label

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

In my app i have a UILabel and a UIImageView under each other. Both of them have a fixed width, but their height supposed to change.
I want the UILabel's height to change to fit the text it's holding and i want the UIImageView's height to change automatically to fill the width and keep it's aspect ratio.
My problem is that autolayout doesn't allow me to have both item's vertical content compression resistance priority to the same constant. Because of this one item will always oppress the other.

What i expect is the tableviewcell to change it's height dynamically to fit its content. 
I do not want to modify anything from code.

Comment: Any screenshot you can provide?

Comment: I cannot, it's work-related.

Comment: You can set a constraint from the top of your `UILabel` to the top of the `UITableViewCell` and the bottom of the label to the bottom of the cell. That way whenever the label or image change height the top/bottom of the cell will always be X points away.

Comment: But this way they wont keep the same distance from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in alot possible way like

1.) Using **StackView**  here is a link to help http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

2.) You can select your `UILabel` and its `superView` than select `aspectRatio` , in a same way select your `UIImageView` and the `superView` than select `aspectRatio`.

It will help Thanks.

Comment: The first answer is correct, unfortunately i need to support ios8 too.
The second answer is unfortunately that's not true. I want the both the label and the imageview to keep the same width, and expand down as much as they need to show their full content. Setting their aspect ratio will keep them the same height all the time (since their width is fixed)